# No verbose output when fork option is used for maven-compiler-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin

If I want to see the compiler output, usually I enable the `verbose` option for the maven-compiler-plugin.

However, this will not work when it is used together with the `fork` option. 
The compilation is running in another process and it seems that maven does not redirect the output to console.

My code sample looks like this

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Does anyone know how can I see what is happening during compilation?

In this [link](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html) I see that using the two options together (fork and verbose) is encouraged.

However, as I already mentioned, in practice the two options do not work well when used
together.

Comment: Can confirm this. Weirdly enough, I can't find a bug report on that. The closest seems to be https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-81 but it was auto-closed =/.

Comment: @Tunaki I do perform an auto-close once a year with the consent of the other devs to clean up JIRA. Tickets haven't been touched for at least three years will never be touched again, regardless they are important or not.

Comment: @Michael-O I'm writing an answer, it looks like a bug inside the plexus compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE (25/06/2016)**: [This issue](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/issues/20) of the `plexus-compiler` was fixed and the given code in the question will work as of version 2.8.

---

After reading through the source code, this is a bug of the [`plexus-compiler`](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler) 2.7, which is the library internally used by the `maven-compiler-plugin` 3.5.1 to compile the Java sources.

So it goes like this in the code: the `maven-compiler-plugin` populates an object called [`CompilerConfiguration`](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.7/plexus-compiler-api/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/CompilerConfiguration.java) and sets its [`fork`](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.7/plexus-compiler-api/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/CompilerConfiguration.java#L79) and [`verbose`](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.7/plexus-compiler-api/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/CompilerConfiguration.java#L93) according to the given configuration element in the POM. The `verbose` element [is correctly read and added to the compiler arguments](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.7/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/javac/JavacCompiler.java#L296-L299):

> ```
> if ( config.isVerbose() )
> {
>     args.add( "-verbose" );
> }
> ```

Then, there is a switch [depending on whether we're forking or not](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.7/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/javac/JavacCompiler.java#L146).

---

If we are not, we eventually come down to the code invoking `javac` and its output [is stored in the compilation result](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.7/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/javac/JavacCompiler.java#L574-L576):

> ```
> ok = (Integer) compile.invoke( null, new Object[]{ args, new PrintWriter( out ) } );
>
> messages = parseModernStream( ok.intValue(), new BufferedReader( new StringReader( out.toString() ) ) );
> ```

finally [returned with](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.7/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/javac/JavacCompiler.java#L596):

> ```
> return new CompilerResult( success, messages );
> ```

So far so good, the `maven-compiler-plugin` will loop around those messages and output them into the console. Since the `verbose` parameter was set, we'll have all messages.

---

If we are, then an executable (which defaults to the `javac` in the PATH) is retrieved and [the compiler arguments are correctly set](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.7/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/javac/JavacCompiler.java#L463-L469):

> ```
> for ( String key : config.getCustomCompilerArgumentsAsMap().keySet() )
> {
>     if ( StringUtils.isNotEmpty( key ) && key.startsWith( "-J" ) )
>     {
>         cli.addArguments( new String[]{ key } );
>     }
> }
> ```

We can confirm this by running Maven in debug mode with `-X`, we'll see the message:

```
[DEBUG] Excutable: 
[DEBUG]  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin\javac.exe"
[DEBUG] Command line options:
[DEBUG] -d ... -classpath ... -sourcepath ... -s ... -g -target 1.8 -source 1.8 -verbose
```

Notice the `-verbose` at the end.

And then, this is the bug. The standard output will be stored inside an [`out`](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.7/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/javac/JavacCompiler.java#L476) variable

> ```
> CommandLineUtils.StringStreamConsumer out = new CommandLineUtils.StringStreamConsumer();
> ```

correctly used as parameter of the compile method, [but completely ignored afterwards](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/blob/plexus-compiler-2.7/plexus-compilers/plexus-compiler-javac/src/main/java/org/codehaus/plexus/compiler/javac/JavacCompiler.java#L508-L510):

> ```
> returnCode = CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine( cli, out, err );
>
> messages = parseModernStream( returnCode, new BufferedReader( new StringReader( err.getOutput() ) ) );
> ```

Notice how the messages, that will later form what is output by the plugin, is only populated with the errors and not the standard output. So put simply: the standard output is correctly set in verbose mode but it is ignored and not translated into the correct compilation result.

---

I do not see a workaround for that (except not forking). I created the [issue 20](https://github.com/codehaus-plexus/plexus-compiler/issues/20) in their GitHub to track this.

Comment: you might want to report this with Plexus Compiler. PRs are welcome and I am eager to merge.

Comment: @Michael-O I created it. Will try to work on a patch when I get the time :)!

Comment: The issue was fixed upstream, you may want to update your post.